# jQuery: addClass and remove from all siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function set up that adds an `active` class to each element as it reaches the top of the browser, thus then fixing it so the next element will scroll in over the top of it. It works great in Chrome but when I'm testing in Safari it seems to be really jumpy.

I can see in the code that the `$('.content').removeClass();` is interfering with the `addClass` function, I somehow need to write a function that adds the class when the `scroller-slide` reaches the top, but removes it from ALL of it's siblings children, is there a clean way to write this?

I have a codepen demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrqRzR

My jQuery markup is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.scroller-slide:first-child').children('.content').addClass('active');

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.scroller-slide').filter(function() {
          $('.content').removeClass('active');   
          return scrolled >= $(this).offset().top-0;
        }).children('.content').addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you remove a class inside the `filter` function, it runs that same code on every element matching the `.scroller-slide` class, on every single scroll ?

Comment: You could try putting the slide's top offsets in a global array on document load & on resize refresh these values. Then in the on scroll function, you only have to search for the highest value that is above the top and add the active class. If that slide already has active as class, don't change anything, else, remove all active classes and only set the current/last one. This might safe on processing and won't interfere as much.

Comment: @Philip cheers Philip! Have you got a code example, or could you try it out in the codepen?

Comment: @user1374796 Yep, I posted it as an answer. I only changed the JavaScript, so have a look at that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, try to minimize the number of function calls in the `scroll` event. Therefore store the top offset values of the slides in a global array, so they don't have to be calculated on every pixel you scroll. Update these values on resize.

In the scroll event, check for the last slide to scroll above the window's top (use the global array). Then check if this slide already has the `active` class. If so, leave everything the way it is. If not, remove all `active` classes from the slides (which is only 1 element). And then `addClass('active')` to the last slide to scroll above top.

I made a example based on your CodePen, hope it helps:

NB: You can reduce function calls if you would set the `active` class to the `.scroller-slide` element itself. (Because you don't have to traverse and check for the child `.content` element.) You would have to adjust the JS and CSS ofcourse for that.

```js
// Set global top offset values
var slide_offsets;
var last_slide;

  $(document).ready(function () {
        Resize();
    });
    
    $(window).load(function () {
        Resize();
    });

    //Every resize of window
    $(window).resize(function () {
        Resize();
    });

    //Dynamically assign height
    function Resize() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            finalHeight = windowHeight + 'px';

        $('.fullscreen').css('min-height', finalHeight);

        // Reset offset values
        slide_offsets = null;
        slide_offsets = [];
      
        // Update offset values
        $('.scroller-slide').each(function(i, el){
          slide_offsets[ i ] = $(this).offset().top-0;
        });
    }

    //Fix Elements on Scroll

 $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('.scroller-slide').eq(0).find('> .content').addClass('active');
  
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();

            // Reset last_slide
            last_slide = 0;
          
            // Get last slide to scroll above top
            $.each(slide_offsets, function(i,v){
                if ( v <= scrolled ) {
                    last_slide = i;
                }
            });
      
            // Check if any slide is above top and that last slide is not yet set to class 'active'
            if ( last_slide >= 0 && 
                ! $('.scroller-slide').eq( last_slide ).children('.content').hasClass('active') ) {
         
                // Remove all 'active' classes from slide .content's (which will be 1 item)
                $('.scroller-slide > .content.active').removeClass('active');
                
                // Set class 'active' to last slide to scroll above top
                $('.scroller-slide').eq( last_slide ).find('>.content').addClass('active');
            }
        });
  
 });
```

```css
/*
RESETS ------------------------
*/ 

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: ;background: transparent;}

/*
RESETS END --------------------
*/

.scroller-slide {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.scroller-slide .content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}

.scroller-slide .content.image-background {
 background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.scroller-slide .content .inner-scroller-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.scroller-slide .active {
 position: fixed !important;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}

.scroller-slide .active .inner-scroller-content {
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller-slide fullscreen">
     <div class="content colour-background" style="background-color: #939597;">
        <div class="inner-scroller-content">
          Slide 01
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="scroller-slide fullscreen">
     <div class="content colour-background" style="background-color: #f7a986;">
        <div class="inner-scroller-content">
          Slide 02
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="scroller-slide fullscreen">
     <div class="content colour-background" style="background-color: #d2b63a;">
        <div class="inner-scroller-content">
          Slide 03
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a really minimal way to have this effect with just adding and removing classes with jquery each function.  First start out with a wrapper for each section and then add and remove the active class to this section wrapper.  Then fix the section inside of the section wrapper.

here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/bxf5f32b/)

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {
    $( ".section-wrapper" ).each(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
              $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Then the css

```
.section-wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}
.section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.section-wrapper.active .section{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section" style="background: #111;">Section 1</div>
</div>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section" style="background: #222;">Section 2</div>
</div>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section" style="background: #333;">Section 3</div>
</div>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section" style="background: #444;">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's minimal in size of code, but not in performance. The OP reports problems with performance, because JS has to do a lot of work for every pixel that is scrolled. So the trade-off is size of code vs. processing time. I would focus on the latter, since that's the bottleneck here, and even more so for mobile devices